# COB LED unwanted blinking

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current, cob

I'm testing a  [Cree CXB1304](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/723/ds_CXB1304-2326680.pdf) powered by a constant current driver [Meanwell LPV-35-36](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/260/MWEC_S_A0011715787_1-2552062.pdf)

This setup makes the LED blink regularly every 2 secs, as [I've read](https://www.instyleled.co.uk/what-causes-led-flicker-and-how-can-i-stop-it-happening/) this occurs when the driver has insufficient specs.

I have a basic understanding of diodes and to me if the voltage is enough the LED should work and consume the current it is given. In this setup the driver output voltage is higher than the LED requirement, but the driver output current is equal to the requirement.

So I should overshoot my driver output current? And if so, by wich amount ?

To go further: if I put several LEDs in series, can you confirm that the voltage will be constant and I should multiply the current requirement by the *n* number of LEDs + overshoot? In that case, should I multiply the overshoot current by *n* too ?

Answer (score 4):

[image: LPV-35]

This sounds like your load is tripping the overcurrent protection on the power supply, which is constant voltage.  You need some way to limit the amount of current going into the diode.  Whether that's using a CC supply, series resistor, or some other sort of driver circuit is up to you, but right now your power supply's built in protection is the only thing keeping it from burning up your LED.

Putting multiple LEDs in series will add their voltages while keeping their currents identical.

Comment: Damn constant voltage it is, I thought I filtered them out on the website... Thanks

Comment: @maximg Had that supply been constant current it would have burned up the LED almost instantly, so you got a little lucky that the constant voltage supply overcurrent protection kicked in. You need to buy a driver that drives the correct current for the LED, which in this case is 100mA.